# Is it possible to install a clean Android on new Amazon Fire HD 10?

Tags: rooting, amazon-kindle-fire-hd

I see that Amazon is selling Fire HD 10 for $99. Aside from not wanting to see their ads I am deeply suspicious of Alexa spyware and not interested.

I have seen claims that FIre HD 10s 2017 could be rooted, but don't know what model the current ones are:

[https://www.amazon.com/Amazon-Fire-HD-10-Inch-Tablet-32GB-Black/dp/B01J6RPGKG/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=fire+hd&qid=1555563314&s=gateway&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01J6RPGKG)

Is there a known way to ideally install a clean Android on the new Fire HD, or worst case, is there a way to disable the ads, the Alexa spyware etc.

https://www.tweakhound.com/2018/12/18/hacking-my-amazon-fire-hd-10/